# Animated GIF is stopping in IE but works in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to show animated GIF on button click but it is frozen in IE (8,9), works in IE11 , FF and in Chrome.

Is there any workaround.

Here is the html code;

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <title></title>

            <style type="text/css">

            .cssbox-progress { 
            background-image: url('images/3.gif'); 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;  
            }

            .loading
            {
                width: 50px;
                height: 10px;
                 display: none;
                background-color: White;                  
            }

        </style>

        <script >
            function ShowProgress() {
                setTimeout(function () {

                    var loading = $(".loading");
                    loading.show();
                }, 200);
            }
            function test() {
                ShowProgress();
            }

        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                 <div class="loading" align="center" style="width: 50px; height: 10px; ">

                <div class="cssbox-progress" style="width: 50px; height: 10px;"></div>

                </div>

      <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Login" onclientclick ="test()"  />


            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Animated GIF

[image]

Comment: I strongly doubt IE 8 and 9 support animated GIF as div background image. Use <img> tag instead (why don't you?) Besides, your code shows `$(".loading")`, and `$(".loading")` is just an empty div. I think it does exactly what it's supposed to do :)

Comment: i am not sure if i can use image tag as GIF image needs to be set in css.

Comment: Yes you can use image tag. This is the issue as Jeremy says, background image on IE8,9 is not supported for animation.

Comment: can i set image src in css? CSS is not used to define values to DOM element attributes

Comment: Yes  `content : url("images/3.gif")`

Comment: <img> within div class="cssbox-loading" ?

Comment: okay. i have tried <img> within div and it works fine if i set image src on page but doesn't work when set it through css.It needs to be set through css.

Comment: if you need to show hide the image, then just use `display: inline-block` and `display: none`, why change the source to begin with?

Comment: there are two different GIF animated images and they need to be set in css depending on user's selected theme on web page.

Comment: I have tried quite a few different things but no luck. I ended up setting image source at run time from code behind page depends on user's selected theme. I have tested in IE8, 9 and 11, FF and Chrome as well. Strangely it doesn't work if i set css at run time but works if i set url.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comments, here is the scenario:
1- you need to show a "loading" animated gif.
2- the gif is not animated in IE 8/9.
3- you need to change the source in css since you're using themes.

and the answer is

```
<style>
.cssbox-progress { 
     content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS784.gif'); 
}
</style>
```

and

```
<img class="cssbox-progress" />
```

I didn't test it on IE 8 / 9 though, I use a plugin to test how it might look like, but you should test it to make sure.